# Поворот экрана на Android из Love2D

Tags: lua

Вот и вся проблема: как перевернуть экран из горизонтального положения в вертикальное с помощью Love2D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вращения используется функция [love.graphics.rotate](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.rotate)

Comment: Эта функция используется для вращения объектов. Конечно, с её помощью можно организовать костыль для решения задачи, но и спрашиваю конкретно про поворот экрана и изменение ориентации окна (если это понятие применимо в Android)

Comment: Эта функция вращает абсолютно всё, что было отрисовано после её вызова, внутри love.draw(). Если вы вызовите её в самом начале, то она будет вращать весь экран. Это не костыль, так и задумано. Аналогичные функции, например love.graphics.scale, работают идентично.

Comment: Это и получается костыль, разве нет? Ведь в таком случае отрисовка всё равно идёт на горизонтальный экран. Вращается лишь изображение внутри

Comment: В Love2d нет возможности перевернуть картинку на экране внутренними средствами  android, но с точки зрения производительности нет никакой разницы. Такой функции нет, потому что она не нужна. love.graphics.rotate лишь устанавливает угол для отрисовки кадров, это не вызывает никакой особой нагрузки (если вы думаете, что она переворачивает объекты по отдельности, то это не так, вращаются не объекты, а координатная система).

Comment: Если быть точным, то нет никаких "объектов", есть лишь кадры, которые отрисовываются 60 раз в секунду и движку безразлично, под каким углом их рисовать. Когда вы вращаете что-то отдельное на экране, вы лишь временно меняете общий угол.

Comment: Ладно, благодарю за ответ! Придётся использовать его